# Nginx possible bug with dashes (-) in server_name

Tags: nginx, web-server, unix

The following Nginx (v 1.2.1) configuration

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name aaa.example.com;
    root /var/www/aaa;
}

server {

    listen 80;
    server_name hello-world.example.com;
    root /var/www/hello;
}
```

because the server_name of the second server contains a `dash` (`-`), nginx will always open the second server (whether you go to hello-world.example.com or aaa.example.com)

I fixed it by renaming `hello-world` to `helloworld` (removing the dash fixed the issue).

Isn't this a bug in Nginx?

Comment: Seems very unlikely, since you would be the first to experience such an issue. You most likely have misconfigured _something else_. Describe your entire environment. Leave nothing out.

Comment: You may want to consider upgrading Nginx.

Comment: @TanHongTat Still happens on Nginx 1.4.1

Comment: @MichaelHampton default Nginx configuration

Comment: That doesn't really describe _anything_.

Answer (score 4):

This is a bit far-fetched, but try adding this line inside the `http` context in nginx config:

```
server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
```

Then restart nginx and see if the name with `-` works.

Comment: I had the same problem as OP and this solved it for me.

Comment: While this change was key, I actually had to go higher than 64 for a long domain name. In my case I chose 128, and that solved the issue.